# Split up forms for user input in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

This is an easy question, but I don't know how to word it to get a result from Google.

I am currently building an app in Android. One of the features of the app includes inputting a large amount of personal data (i.e. emergency contact information, social security number, and others). The file will include around 40 fields, but I don't want the user to have to scroll through one layout to fill all this information out. Thus, how do I create new "forms" to populate without having to create a new activity and xml layout for each set of data?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: the answer is to use new activities. Or tab activities. But the result is the same, you need more xmls, unless the fields all match type, in which case you can just reuse the same xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thus, how do I create new "forms" to populate without having to create a new activity and xml layout for each set of data?

You are welcome to create a new fragment and XML layout for each set of data, if you prefer.

At the end of the day, your code is largely the same in all cases:

- You need all 40 fields in an XML layout file somewhere. Whether this is one file, two files, or ten files, is up to you.
- You need to your controller logic for handling that input from those 40 fields somewhere. Whether that is in one activity, N activities, or N fragments, is up to you.

If you are expecting Android tools to be able to magically generate all this for you, just by you thinking really hard and staring at your monitor, Google's Project Synapse has not yet been released yet. :-)

Comment: I was really looking to make it easier for the user to work with as I don't want to overwhelm them with too many fields to input.

Comment: @thePhilosopher: But that's not what you asked. You asked how to eliminate the work to accomplish that ("...without having to create a new activity and xml layout for each set of data"). Your UI vision is perfectly reasonable. I'd consider a wizard structure, for example. However, that requires programming, and that programming may well require new classes and resources.

Comment: I see, the wizard structure is what I was looking for. Thank you and sorry for the bad focus of my question.

Comment: @thePhilosopher: Here is an open source Google-authored wizard framework: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/wizardpager/ Note that I haven't tried it, but usually Roman Nurik's code is solid.